# Network default is not accessible to Dataflow Service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Having issues starting a Dataflow job(`2018-07-16_04_25_02-6605099454046602382`) in a project without a local VPC Network when I get this error

```
Workflow failed. Causes: Network default is not accessible to Dataflow
Service account
```

There is a shared VPC connected to the project with a networked called `default` with a subnet `default` in `us-central1` – however the service account used to run dataflow job don't seam to have access to it. I have given the `dataflow-service-producer` service account `Compute Network User`, without any noticeable effect. Any ideas on how I can processed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usage of subnetworks in Cloud Dataflow requires to specify the subnetwork parameter when running the pipeline; However, in the case of subnetwork that are located in a Shared VPC network, it is required to use the **complete URL** based on the following format, as you well mentioned.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<HOST_PROJECT>/regions/<REGION>/subnetworks/<SUBNETWORK>
```

Additionally, in this cases is recommended to verify that you are adding the project's Dataflow service account into the Shared VPC's project IAM table and give it the **"Compute Network User"** role permission in order to ensure that the service has the required access scope.

Finally, it is seems that the [Subnetwork parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#subnetwork_parameter) official Google's documentation is alraedy available with detailed information about this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `--subnetwork` [option](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options) with the following (undocumented) fully qualified subnetwork format made the Dataflow job run. Where `{PROJECT}` is the name of the project hosting the shared VPC and `{REGION}` matches the region you run your dataflow job in.

```
--subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/{PROJECT}/regions/{REGION}/subnetworks/{SUBNETWORK}
```