# Dataflow Job is failing within 40 Seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple google could http trigger function which is responsible for triggering Dataflow runner job that loads data from CSV on Cloud Storage to a BigQuery table.

My code looks is given below:-

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions, PipelineOptions

PROJECT = 'proj'
BUCKET='BUCKET'
SCHEMA = 'sr:INTEGER,abv:FLOAT,id:INTEGER,name:STRING,style:STRING,ounces:FLOAT,ibu:STRING,brewery_id:STRING'
DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME = 'jobname'


def execute(request):
    argv = [
      '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
      '--job_name={0}'.format(DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME),
      '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--region=europe-west2',
      '--runner=DataflowRunner'
   ]

    #p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(argv)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    input = 'gs://{0}/beers.csv'.format(BUCKET)
    print ('step-222')

    (p | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input, skip_header_lines =1)
       | 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
       | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"sr": x[0], "abv": x[1], "ibu": x[2], "id": x[3], "name": x[4], "style": x[5], "brewery_id": x[6], "ounces": x[7]}) 
       | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
           table='data',
           dataset='sandbox',
           project=PROJECT
           schema=SCHEMA,
           create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
           ))
    p.run()
    return "success"
```

Function runs successfully and it also creates a Dataflow instance, but Dataflow instance fails with in 40 seconds without creating Graph-View.
[image]
It is giving error :- [image]

Comment: What is the error message (the red bubble at the botoom of your sreenshot)?

Comment: It's edited and added.

Comment: Looks like a permission/VPC/subnetwork issue. Have you tried any standard solutions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362560/network-default-is-not-accessible-to-dataflow-service-account)

Comment: You should fix your network config when you run your dataflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @captainnabla said in his comment, you have to create a [subnetwork](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks) and give it as option to your `Dataflow` job.

- Solution 1

In the default `VPC` of the project, create the subnetwork for `Dataflow`

If you didn’t specified the subnetwork, usually the project default VPC network will be used by the Dataflow job. I don’t know why this didn’t worked in your case (maybe in this case, the default network taken by the job is outside of the project executing the job).

- Solution 2

Create another `VPC` for your data pipelines and a subnetwork for `Dataflow`

**The network config depends on your team strategy.**

In the two solutions, you can pass the subnetwork as program argument to your `Dataflow` job :

```
--subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/regions/{REGION}/subnetworks/{SUBNETWORK}
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks Mazlum. Just wanted to add that "default" is the default network used in case it is not specified (and should exist by default in most projects), so somehow it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You’re welcome Bruno, you are right and thanks for these details.